Add MultipartFile to Unirest field?
The current code below works as expected, however I want to be able to use org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile file instead of new File("watch.jpg"), is that possible? or does the MultipartFile need to be saved to an actual file on the disk first?
   kong.unirest.core.HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.post("https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media")
            .basicAuth("username", "pass")
            .field("file", new File("watch.jpg"))
            .asJson();


Here is how it's done
.field("file", file.getInputStream(), file.getOriginalFilename())

